# How does one set Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcuts comfortably, especially when using ReSharper?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, resharper

In every Visual Studio.NET version you can set keyboard shortcuts using menu *Tools* -> *Options* -> *Environment* -> *Keyboard* and then find the command you want to assign a shortcut to by entering part of it in "Show commands containing".

For one thing, the listbox is ridiculously short and hard to navigate - is there an alternative?

Then, how do I find out the correct command name for a specific action?

Specifically, I'm using ReSharper 5.1 with [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) and want to have the <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> shortcut back (it used to be there in older versions by default) that opens the ReSharper context menu when the cursor is over a curly underline ReSharper uses to highlight errors or warnings.

How do I find out the command name for that (except by an educated guess)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The way I do this is to perform an action while recording a macro (using Tools / Macro / Record temporary macro).

When I have finished with the action, I look at the source code of the macro and it usually helps to find the correct command.

For example, I have just let R# add some magic through Alt-Enter, and the macro recorder has:

```
DTE.ExecuteCommand("ReSharper_QuickFix")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rebind **all** of the ReSharper shortcuts by using the ReSharper -> Options -> Visual Studio Integration page. Select a keyboard scheme and hit "Apply Scheme".

Comment: I know, but that doesn't help me to find a specific command, it just resets everything to one or the other default scheme.

Comment: Yeah, I know, but that might have been your actual problem. The Alt+Enter shortcut in R# is called "Quick Fix". Might help you find it.

Comment: The "Quick Fix" hints solved my actual problem - thanks indeed!

The other question, however, remains: how do you find out that this is called "Quick fix" (for example)?

Comment: From that dialog, no idea. I found out in an email conversation with JetBrains a couple of years ago.