# Visual Studio shortcut for "quick fix"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, keyboard-shortcuts

Does Visual Studio 2010 have a shortcut for quick fix?

I'm tired of grabbing the mouse, hovering over this red line, waiting for the little clipboard icon to appear, clicking on the first menu item. It would be so much fast to just open that dialog with some keys and confirming the first (i.e. selected) item.

Comment: Have a look at [ReSharper](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReSharper). It is very useful for many quick fixes, refactoring and unit testing.

Comment: Thanks for this question .. trying to hover over that little line was driving me nuts

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The feature is called the "**Smart Tag**".

1. *[Default Keyboard Shortcut Schemes](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Keyboard_Shortcuts.html)* (ReSharper documentation)
2. Stack Overflow question *[How does one set Visual Studio 2010 keyboard shortcuts comfortably, especially when using ReSharper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725007)*
3. **Stack Overflow question** ***[Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to automatically add the needed 'using' statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/148977)***

They can usually be invoked via the keyboard using either:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> (on a standard [QWERTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QWERTY) keyboard)
2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> (if you've not got Function Lock enabled)

Answer (score 17):

Place your cursor/caret on the underlined item, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to pop up the intellisence/suggestion context menu.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F10</kbd> does the trick.

Via @Rohit from [Visual Studio keyboard shortcut to automatically add the needed using statement](https://stackoverflow.com/a/148985/197574)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to edit the shortcut of quick fix you can do the following:
Open `Tools->Options->Keyboard` and in the `Show commands containing` field enter `EditorContextMenus.CodeWindow.QuickActionsForPosition` and replace the old shortcut with the new one.

Comment: `Tools -> Options -> Keyboard` is super useful when looking for command ids to map VsVim bindings to them. I've been looking for the command ids all over the place with no luck until I saw your answer, thank you!