# How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I would like to change the keyboard shortcut for *quick fix* in Visual Studio 2013, so that it matches the ReSharper equivalent (which I only use on my office machine). How can I do it?

Comment: Maybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9786144/visual-studio-shortcut-for-quick-fix

Comment: Look at this doc: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022

Answer (score 32, accepted):

One way to do it is to enter on the menu 'Tools', 'Customize' and click on the 'Keyboard...' button near the 'Close' button.

Inside this option you can search for the commands by name (I couldn't find the Quick Fix here), maybe you want the `Edit.FormatDocument` one, that makes the indentation for the documents automatically.

If you can't find this option, tell me your quick fix actual keyboard shortcut, so I'll be able to check which function it calls.

I did some research on the R# QuickFix option and maybe what you want is this is the option you want: `View.ShowSmartTag`.

Comment: Can I create a combination like "shift + shift", like with intelliJ? ( The key pressed twice in quick succession )

Comment: @NavidKhan I am almost sure it's not possible to use the shift+shift in either Visual Studio or Visual Studio Code. Sadly.

Comment: "Near the Close button", litteraly saved my life lol

Answer (score 3):

Look at this doc: [Identify and customize keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/identifying-and-customizing-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2022)

[image]

[image]