# Ctrl + R not working for running the program in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, ctrl

I have this program all of a sudden. I was coding fine in visual studio and i guess i pressed a combination which changed a setting. I always used ctrl + r to run the program, as soon as im ready to test something i press ctrl + r and the program ran. But for pass few hours when i press ctrl + r it shows :

ctrl + r was pressed. waiting for second key of cord.

I tried to reset all keyboard shortcut and had no luck.
Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue please its really annoying.

And oh im programming in c++ and used visual studio for quite a few months and it worked perfectly in visual studio 2017 without any issues until now.

Comment: Strange, I've always used Cntrl+F5. Just F5 runs but then closes the console again (assuming it's a console program). Cntrl keeps the console open so that you can see the output your program gave.

Comment: If you have accidentally set keybindings, you can look at them in your currentsettings.vssettings file, located in your profile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change my development environment to a different language in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/967309/how-do-i-change-my-development-environment-to-a-different-language-in-visual-stu)

Comment: Tools > Customize > Keyboard.  Click on "Press shortcut keys" and type Ctrl+R.  The combobox at the bottom shows all commands it is bound to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I change the keyboard shortcuts in Visual Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21740261/608639)

Comment: ah ok, thanks a lot guys, i really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Never heard of using <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to run a program in Visual Studio.

Use <kbd>F5</kbd> to run with debugger or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> to run without debugger attached.

Comment: But what if someone wants to use `Ctrl` + `R` to run/debug the project? How can you do that? This crappy Microsoft software doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: @Tim Tools -> Options -> Environment -> Keyboard: "Show Commands Containing": "Debug.Start" and "Debug.StartWithoutDebugging"
Feel free to change F5 and CRTL+F5 to whatever you want. Thank "crappy Microsoft software" for letting you change keyboard shortcuts.

Comment: That's what I did, but every time I press `Ctrl` + `R` it says ``(Ctrl + R) was pressed. Waiting for secound key of chord...`. As I said, crappy Microsoft software

Comment: @Tim That's most likely PEBKAC. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57711883/3975177