# Visual Studio Code waiting for second key of chord. (Ctrl + A)

Tags: visual-studio-code

When I try to select all of the text in a file, I receive a notification that says:

```
(Ctrl + A) was pressed. Waiting for second key of chord...
```

Here is a screenshot of my "select all" keyboard shortcuts. How can I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to select all text instead of getting a chord notification?

[image]

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_detecting-keybinding-conflicts

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73915603/i-can-not-type-n-letter-in-my-visual-studio-code?noredirect=1#comment130513565_73915603

Answer (score 74, accepted):

You have another key binding that begins with Ctrl+A, something like this:

[image: Screenshot of key bindings with Ctrl+A prefix]

A sequence of multiple keystrokes pressed one after another (rather than simultaneously) is called a "chord".

You might have accidentally created it, or might have recently installed an extension that adds the problematic binding.  To find it, do like I have done in the screenshot and type "ctrl a" into the Keyboard Shortcuts search box (that tab can be opened by typing Ctrl+K then Ctrl+S).  Then look for a binding that begins with Ctrl+A but has something else after it (in my case, another Ctrl+A, but it could be almost anything).

When you find the offending binding, right-click on it, and either remove or change it.  Then Ctrl+A alone will resume working.

Note: This question and its answer pertain to [Visual Studio Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Studio_Code), which is different from [Visual Studio](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio).  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21035286/waiting-for-second-key-of-chord) for information about the equivalent situation in Visual Studio.

Comment: I was suffering from this problem for a while but you saved my life! Thank you for the solution!

Comment: It would seem this could be handled more elegantly if instead of trapping for a namespace collision the keystroke delay could be interrogated.  For example, if after 2 seconds, then simply perform <Ctrl + A>.  The delay would be arbitrary and most likely a settable parameter.

Comment: how do you search for shortcuts? Doesn't seem to work in the Ctrl+Q of Vs2022

Comment: @sofsntp This question is for VSCode, not VS.  I just edited my answer to add a link to the equivalent question for VS.

Comment: Thanks you so much your answer is correct

Comment: From the Keyboard Shortcuts preferences, I clicked the keyboard icon to the right of the search field, and pressed the problem combo (Cmd+L in my case), but the only shortcut that showed up was the default Cmd+L.  Turns out this is searching for an exact match.  I deleted the quotes in the search field, and was able to find all keybindings that used Cmd+L, including two chords coming from an extension.

Answer (score 3):

I was in a situation where `Ctrl+x` did not work and was considered the start of a keychord. Every time I pressed `Ctrl+x`, instead of cutting the selected text, the editor told me that it was waiting for the second key of the chord.

Looking at "Preferences->Keyboard shortcuts" did not help. Searching for `Ctrl+X` in the list showed that only the "Cut" command was mapped to this key.

I had to edit the file `$HOME/.config/Code/User/keybindings.json` (under Linux) and search for `CTRL+x`. It turned out another command was mapped to a keychord starting with this key combination. I am not sure know how I got in this situation.

Comment: it was "C:\Users\THINKPAD\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\keybindings.json" on my machine,but there is a button for it  on the top right on the Keyboard Shortcuts tab in VS code

Answer (score 2):

You might be in a situation where you want to keep the chorded keybindings that are causing you the problem with your original keybinding. A potential workaround to this issue is turning your original keybinding into a chord as well. For example, you could having a 'stop' character that exits your chord. For example, "Ctrl+A ." where "." is your stop character.

So if for some reason you really liked "Ctrl+A" as the beginning keystroke for a bunch of chorded keybindings, then rebinding all current "Ctrl+A" keybindings to "Ctrl+A ." would free up that keystroke for any manner of other, chorded keybindings.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, reloading VS Code with extensions disabled fixed it, so I knew it was an extension. Took a while, but eventually figured out it was https://github.com/phsantos/nano-id-generator.

Comment: Thank you, for me it was "go to node_modules" extension

Comment: This was helpful. I was more selective in disabling editing non-must haves, but that seemed to free up some basic key combos I needed.