# I can not type n letter in my visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

when I press n letter in my visual studio code editor it doesn't type

In the bottom of the editor I get this alert:
"(N) was pressed waiting for second key of chord.."

I tried the solution here :
[Visual Studio Code waiting for second key of chord. (Ctrl + A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456894/visual-studio-code-waiting-for-second-key-of-chord-ctrl-a/73914897?noredirect=1#comment130512351_73914897)
but also nothing changed

please how I can solve this problem ?
there is nothing which I can edit in my shortcuts!!!
[image: ][1]]
this is what I am getting after pressing n

[image]

==>> Also I tried to disable all visual studio code's extensions but the problem did not solve

my keybindings.json

```
"key": "n t",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"

    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"

    "key": "a m",
    "command": "notebook.cell.changeToMarkdown",
    "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.notebook' && notebookCellType == 'code'"
  {
    "key": "m",
    "command": "-notebook.cell.changeToMarkdown",
    "when": "notebookEditorFocused && !inputFocus && activeEditor == 'workbench.editor.notebook' && notebookCellType == 'code'"
  }
```

Comment: Look for your `keybindings.json` and post it here.

Comment: Don't post it to a comment - **edit your question post instead**

Comment: The issue is your first keybinding, `{ "key": "n t", ... }`. When you press the `n` key, visual studio code doesn't know if you meant to type the `n` key by itself or are trying to use the `n t` shortcut, so it's waiting for you to press `t`. You will have to remove that one. I imagine `{ key: 'a m', ... }` and `{ key: 'm', ... }` will also be problematic.

Comment: thanks a lot 
my problem is solved after removing what you suggested:
my keybinding.json now is: 
[
  {
    "key": "ctrl+shift+c",
    "command": "-workbench.action.terminal.openNativeConsole",
    "when": "!terminalFocus"
  }
]
please If I have to do anything else let me know ?

Comment: If you didn't set any of those on purpose, I'd say remove them all. Only include in `keybindings.json` values _you_ want (these are custom configs which can be different for everyone). If your keybinds file is only an empty array, you will use the defaults, and you'll be fine.

Comment: yes I did not
thanks a lot