# Visual Studio Code waiting for second key of chord. (Ctrl + G)

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

In VSCode I wanted to install some extensions to have a to-do list. None of them worked in the way I wanted so I uninstalled them. However, when I try to type `g` I get the message:

> Visual Studio Code waiting for second key of chord. (Ctrl + G)

I've scoured the solutions in this:

[Visual Studio Code waiting for second key of chord. (Ctrl + A)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456894/visual-studio-code-waiting-for-second-key-of-chord-ctrl-a)

And it doesn't work. I was trying to see how to see if there was a way of removing the settings json file so I could see out keybindings but don't know how to do that.

I have considered deleting the keybindings.json file but I can't find it. And if I did? what do I do to replace it with a default?

I did reinstall the program but it has kept its settings. It is a Mac.

Comment: Do you mean that when you opened the settings for the keyboard shortcuts and searched for Ctrl-G there was nothing?

Comment: Yes in a word.. Frustrating.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the `Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled` command in the command palette)? If not, then do an [extension bisect](//code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2021/02/16/extension-bisect) to figure out what extension is causing it.

Comment: What do you see when you [troubleshoot your keybindings](//github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/Keybinding-Issues)? Please paste the relevant parts of what you see into a code block in your question post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Go to Keyboard Shortcuts
   [image]
2. Enter `Recording keys` mode
   [image]
3. Type `Ctrl+G` or whatever shortcut you are looking for