# How to completely reset keymappings in VSCode

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I [asked a similar question yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77046451/visual-studio-code-waiting-for-second-key-of-chord-ctrl-g) but the problem has resurfaced but on the character `]`.

Not the same, I just can't get the character to appear and given I use Python and VSCode this is a bugbear.

Is there a way of simply replacing the keybindings in VSCode to default? It doesn't [affect] any other application as far as I can tell.

I'm on Mac.

Comment: just delete all the content of your `keybindings.json`, maybe just leave `{}`

Comment: And where is that on a Mac?

Comment: have you read the key-bind doc page

Comment: Where is that? I''m not a dev.

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings but more specifically I think you are looking for this section https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/keybindings#_advanced-customization

Comment: where did you download VSC

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This link seems to be very useful for your question as it shows how to reset key bindings: https://ourtechroom.com/tech/reset-keyboard-bindings-visual-studio-code/

Or even:

Run *Developer: Toggle Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting* maybe will make the error disappear.

Although I have heard this error is pretty common on heavy use days and is a result of some extension you might have. Would say to disable extensions by running vsCode with **code --disable-extensions** from the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

- Open Finder. Press Cmd + Shift + G to open the "Go to Folder" dialog.
  Type ~/Library/Application Support/Code/User/ and press Enter.

It seems to work for me.